# cImage ValueError: Error: pixel value 300 is out of range

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am learning python through the interactive version of "How to think like a computer scientist" and I am stuck at one exercise in the 8th chapter, it gives me the formula to make a pixel into sepia which is this

```
newR = (R × 0.393 + G × 0.769 + B × 0.189)
newG = (R × 0.349 + G × 0.686 + B × 0.168)
newB = (R × 0.272 + G × 0.534 + B × 0.131)
```

I also use the cImage function that I imported after using pip install, it has also required to install PIL first.

The exercise also warned that rgb values must be integers in the 0-255 range

I wrote the program but it shows me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Γιάννης\Desktop\python\testing.py", line 13, in <module>
    newpix = image.Pixel(newR, newG, newB)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Γιάννης\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\image.py", line 202, in __init__    
    self.setRed(red)
  File "C:\Users\Γιάννης\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\image.py", line 241, in setRed      
    raise ValueError("Error:  pixel value %d is out of range" % red)
ValueError: Error:  pixel value 300 is out of range
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
import image

img = image.Image("luther.jpg")
win = image.ImageWin(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
img.draw(win)

for col in range(img.getWidth()):
    for row in range(img.getHeight()):
        pix = img.getPixel(col, row)
        newR = int((pix.getRed() * 0.393 + pix.getGreen() * 0.769 + pix.getBlue() * 0.189))
        newG = int((pix.getRed() * 0.349 + pix.getGreen() * 0.686 + pix.getBlue() * 0.168))
        newB = int((pix.getRed() * 0.272 + pix.getGreen() * 0.534 + pix.getBlue() * 0.131))
        newpix = image.Pixel(newR, newG, newB)
        img.setPixel(col, row, newpix)

img.draw(win)
win.exitonclick()
```

Comment: You have been explicitly warned that value must be [0,255], you get value error that at least one pixel value is 300 and you wonder why?

Comment: i know what error i have got, i am asking how to fix it, i followed the provided formula to turn it into sepia and get this but i don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the new RGB values calculated using the sepia formula can be greater than 255. To fix this issue, you should clip the new RGB values to the range `0-255` before creating the new pixel. You can use the built-in [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) functions for this:

```
import image


def clip(value: int, lower_limit: int = 0, upper_limit: int = 255) -> int:
    return max(lower_limit, min(value, upper_limit))


img = image.Image("luther.jpg")
win = image.ImageWin(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
img.draw(win)

for col in range(img.getWidth()):
    for row in range(img.getHeight()):
        pix = img.getPixel(col, row)
        newR = clip(int(pix.getRed() * 0.393 + pix.getGreen() * 0.769 + pix.getBlue() * 0.189))
        newG = clip(int(pix.getRed() * 0.349 + pix.getGreen() * 0.686 + pix.getBlue() * 0.168))
        newB = clip(int(pix.getRed() * 0.272 + pix.getGreen() * 0.534 + pix.getBlue() * 0.131))
        newpix = image.Pixel(newR, newG, newB)
        img.setPixel(col, row, newpix)

img.draw(win)
win.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue, although the webpage with the python lessons hasn't showed me the mix/max functions or the syntax you used for the function you wrote

Comment: No problem. The syntax I used is default arguments (so you don't have to pass in 0 and 255 each time), and type hints (so it is easier to enforce people don't call the function with variables that are not integers).